# how to create a query function like sql in nominatim container

Tags: docker-compose, docker-container, nominatim

we installed docker desktop in windows .then created a container with [nominatim manual installation].(https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/)
set all settings in docker-compose.yml file.
my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
    nominatim:
        container_name: nominatim
        image: mediagis/nominatim:4.3
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "50060:8080"
        environment:
            PBF_PATH: /opt/nominatim-pbf/iran-latest.osm.pbf
            NOMINATIM_PASSWORD: very_secure_password
        volumes:
            - ./nominatim-data:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main
            - ./pbfs:/opt/nominatim-pbf
        shm_size: 1gb
```

now i access to nominatim server and i can search in nominatim server with url.for example:
`http://localhost:50060/search?country=Germany&polygon_geojson=1&format=json`
problem: how can i search in database with more parametrs.how can i search in database with sql query or sql function? how to get list of all cities in germany from nominatim container?
is this posible?

i read about python libs in nominatim manual:
[link](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/library/Getting-Started/)
but i could not solve it